How to add javascript class methods from separate file includes
I have been working with a modular backend, nodejs + typescript + esbuild.
This is an app that at it's core is made up of a class module and child modules that add methods to that class (see below with quick pseudo code ... to overtly display the concept of multiple files, one class)
This has been rewritten a few times from class to function, with no real impact to the issue below, but could go either way if there was a solution.
This works great; great data sharing, organization, etc.
However, type definitions are not so great. I had to write a little script that esbuild completes after each build to fake insert all the child methods into the class's methods (works fine, as fine as I can parse myself).
But the actual class method completions don't work. There will never be a app. completion beyond the normal and 'db' specified in the class. Similarly stack traces are mostly anonymous as well.
Similar to the definition script, I have wrote a hack read out of the methods from the files, transform them, and placed them into the main class (pre-processor with custom esbuild watcher) and this "works" but there are some build issues (like always full builds).
Object.protoype* methods adds to the class (or object in that code shape), but they wont instantiate in the class ... eg, console.log(this) will not show them, nor will typescript see them, etc. It doesn't play well with separate files.
In my mind to be something that would make this work; an elusive syntax sugar or build technique; rather than littering code named imports and references.
Thanks so much.
// ./index.ts
import { BigIdea } from "./libs/main";
const app = new BigIdea(...);
app.hot();
app.fun();

// ./libs/main.ts
export Class BigIdea {
    constructor(..) {
        this.db = new PrismaClient(...);

        require("./extra")(this);
        require("./special")(this);
    }
}

// ./out/libs/main.d.ts
export declare class BigIdea {
    db: PrismaClient;
    // fake entries imported from script
    hot():  Promise<void>;
    warn():  Promise<void>;
    cool():  Promise<void>;
    fun():  Promise<void>;
    boring():  Promise<void>;
}

// ./lib/extra.ts
module.exports = (bigidea: any) => {
    bigidea.hot = async () => { ... }
    bigidea.warm = async () => { ... }
    bigidea.cool = async () => { ... }
}

// ./lib/special.ts
module.exports = (heysup: any) => {
    bigidea.fun = async () => { ... }
    bigidea.boring = async () => { ... }
}


Hope this helps answer your problem, for which I see is the problem of adding multiple methods to the class from external sources after you have declared the class. Essentially, I came upon this solution:
class ExtraMethods {
    async hot() { console.log('hot'); }
    async warm() { console.log('warm'); }
    async cool() { console.log('cool'); }
}

class SpecialMethods {
    async fun() { console.log('fun'); }
    async boring() { console.log('boring'); }
}

// helper function to merge the classes, does the equivalent of 'class a extends b, c' if that were possible in regular .ts
function applyMixins(targetClass: any, sourceClasses: any[]) {
    sourceClasses.forEach(sourceClass => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sourceClass.prototype).forEach(name => {
            targetClass.prototype[name] = sourceClass.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}


// lets .ts know that methods from extramethods and specialmethods are going to be in bigidea
interface BigIdea extends ExtraMethods, SpecialMethods {}

class BigIdea {
    db: PrismaClient;

    constructor() {
        this.db = new PrismaClient();
    }
}

// code does the actual merging
applyMixins(BigIdea, [ExtraMethods, SpecialMethods]);


const bigIdeaInstance = new BigIdea();

bigIdeaInstance.fun(); // Output: fun
bigIdeaInstance.hot(); // Output: hot

console.log(bigIdeaInstance.cool); // async cool() { console.log('cool'); }
console.log(bigIdeaInstance.fun); // async fun() { console.log('fun'); } 

Essentially this creates a helper function that helps 'merge' classes together, the equivalent of 'class BigIdea extends ExtraMethods, SpecialMethods' if that were even possible in regular .ts
So now you create an interface 'interface BigIdea extends ExtraMethods, SpecialMethods {}' for the type checking part.
And you run this function 'applyMixins(BigIdea, [ExtraMethods, SpecialMethods]);' for the merging part.
As long as your ExtraMethods and SpecialMethods are wrapped within a class, it should work.

Thank you for the reply, I was able to copypaste this and this pattern works great.
For splitting, putting classes out into separate files with an export prefix and then evoking them like this.
import { ExtraMethods } from "./extra";
import { SpecialMethods } from "./special";
and then including them in the extend and applyMixin;
Then if someone wanted to abstract extra into separates they would do the same inside extra and its children.

glad I could help
